# How can filter posts by tag name in WordPress API?

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, tags

I want to filter posts by tag name,

I tried this query but it is not working:

```
 const req = await fetcher(
  `${URL}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?tags[name]=Drivers`
);
```

Someone knows, How should filter posts by tag name.
Please tell me.